# What St-Jacques de Compostelle routes offers the most sightseeing while remaining well supported?

Tags: france, spain, hiking, recommendations, pilgrimages

I wish to do the St-Jacques-de-Compostelle pilgrimage. I am deciding which path would be best for me.

My main criteria is having lots of support infrastructure (albergues, water access, food, etc.) accessible so I don't need to carry tons of gear. As for sightseeing, I love natural panoramas, especially mountains and the like, but not flatlands. Finally, in terms of hiking difficulty, I would like the start to be easy (to gain experience and a good rhythm), but after a while, I do not mind difficulty.

---

Here are the routes that I'm considering:

Up to St-Jean-Pied-de-Port:

- Leaving from Paris
- Leaving from Vezelay
- Leaving from Le Puy

After St-Jean-Pied-de-Port:

- Camino del Norte
- Camino Frances
- Camino Primitivo

Any other path suggestions are also welcome.

Comment: If you don't get a good response here I think they do pros/cons of hiking routes at http://outdoors.stackexchange.com Also when you say "my criteria include..." what would you consider good? Do you want an easy or a challenging hike? With well-developed or minimal "off-the-beaten-track" infrastructure?

Comment: I've opened a meta post to discuss this as I'm not 100% sure I agree with the decision. http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3787/are-pros-and-cons-opinion-based

Comment: Have a good look at maps with heights on it, around Paris is a big area of flat land, Vezelay is on the top of a steep hill, in an area that is not flat, Le Puy seems more hilly still. You best compare the lay of the land to something you are used to. With your requirements, I would start somewhere north of Vezelay, but not as far north as Paris. But if you come from an area with hills or mountains and are used to walking there, you might well find it flat in the south of France.

Comment: @Willeke, I come from Quebec, it's flat as far as the eye can see.

Comment: Not everywhere ;-)  https://www.flickr.com/photos/40002045@N08/4052861091/in/album-72157622683129082/ and https://www.flickr.com/photos/40002045@N08/4053599738/in/album-72157622683129082/

Comment: Of course, but that's far from my home.

Comment: I would suggest starting in a flattish area, but not as far from Vezelay as Paris, unless you want to include a visit to Paris as start of your route. The area around main cities (Paris included) is mostly not nice to walk and it can take days before you are really out of the urban area and its industrial estates.

Comment: I did the Portuguese route, north from Oporto, and it was simple, well supported, and the people super friendly. But it sounds like you really want to do a route from France....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Leaving from Paris (and presumably going through Tours) is clearly not a good option given your criteria. The area around Paris and the [Centre-Val-de-Loire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centre-Val_de_Loire) are generally flat and the route then goes around the *Massif Central*, without any major mountainous area and generally less dramatic landscape. The [Via Lemovicensis](http://www.chemins-compostelle.com/itineraires/9/la-voie-de-vezelay) also includes many rather flat areas but at least it does cross the *Massif Central*.

So the [Via Podiensis](http://www.chemins-compostelle.com/itineraires/10/la-voie-du-puy-en-velay) seems the best option for you, with one small caveat: Le Puy is in a relatively mountainous area and some of the steepest climbs (apart from the crossing of the Pyrenees, which is common to all three ways) would be at the very beginning (don't imagine the Rockies or even the Alps however). The rest of this route include some *plateau* and many hilly areas (not really mountains but not flat either) and the infrastructure is great.

Because of this, you can basically make the progression as easy as you want by stopping more frequently. Also note that the GR65 is marked all the way to Geneva. You could start somewhere east of Lyon to have a couple of days of relatively flat terrain before approaching Le Puy and the *Massif Central* (not sure about the infrastructure on this part of the way but finding support should not be difficult, it's not a wild area at all).

I am less familiar with the various routes in Spain but my understanding is that the *Camino Frances* is the only one starting in Saint-Jean-Pied-de-Port so that would be the logical option since you are apparently planning to walk one of the major French ways. It certainly boast varied landscape and great support infrastructure.